# Differences between BasicRenderEngine and LazyRenderEngine?

Tags: papervision3d

Anyone out there who knows what are the differences between BasicRenderEngine and LazyRenderEngine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after playing a little bit there seems to be no differences other than some get/set methods and the way they are instantiated.

```
var lazy:LazyRenderEngine = new LazyRenderEngine(scene, camera , viewport);
lazy.render();

var basic:BasicRenderEngine = new BasicRenderEngine();
basic.renderScene(scene, camera, viewport);
```

Maybe the LazyRenderEngine is useful if you want to have multiple render engines with different setups.